# No se suben todas las imágenes PHP

Tags: php

```php
<?php

   $files_post = $_FILES['images'];

   $files = array();
   $file_count = count($files_post['name']);
   $file_keys = array_keys($files_post);
for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++)
{
    foreach($file_keys as $key ){
        $files[$i][$key] = $files_post[$key][$i];
    }
}
foreach($files as $fileID => $file)
{
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    file_put_contents("images/non_watermarked/".$file['name'],$fileContent);
}


?>
```

Trato de subir 40 imágenes pero solo se suben 20, puedo subir 20 y luego las otras 20 pero quiero poder subir las 40 al mismo tiempo. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias
Adjunte una imagen ya que en el navegador si se agregan las 40 imágenes en el array

[image: Solo se suben 20]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, para poder ayudarte mejor agrega tu codigo no imagen del mismo.

Comment: Y de paso agrega el formulario

Comment: Sugiero que depures tu código, así irás sobre seguro. Puedes poner **temporalmente** estas tres líneas al incio de tu script: **`ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`** luego lo guardas y pruebas de nuevo. Copia y pega en la pregunta todos los errores que veas en pantalla pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Revisa la configuración de php.ini, seguramente debas incrementar `max_post_size` y `max_upload_filesize` para poder subir todas. Si procesas las imágenes, también necesitarás incrementar `memory_limit`.

Comment: Efectivamente, tenia que modificar el php.ini **max_post_size** estaba en 40MB (es mas que suficiente) **max_upload_filesize** igual 40MB que también va sobrado, el problema era **max_file_uploads** que tenia 20 y simplemente lo cambie a 40 @Triby gracias por la ayuda, como puedo dar por cerrado la pregunta?

Comment: @AlejandroTorresDominguez Agrega tu mismo la respuesta con esa información detallada para que sea una buena respuesta y acéptala en unas 12 horas (antes no te deja aceptar tus propias respuestas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como me comentaron se tenía que modificar el php.ini

```
max_file_uploads=20
```

se cambió a **40**.

También se verificó **upload_max_filesize** y **post_max_size** que ambos estaban en *40MB* que va muy sobrado en este caso.